# How to queue and write the output of a parallel execution in shell

Tags: shell, queue, jobs, fifo

```
#!/bin/sh

wr_lck=/tmp/write.lck
jobout=/tmp/jobout.log
count=0;

> $jobout;
exec 200>$wr_lck || exit 1

do_job () {

    slptime=$1
    sleep $slptime

    flock -e -w 5 200
    echo  "$count | $slptime" >> $jobout;
    flock -u 200
    echo "Lock released by sub-proc: $count"
}

##-----------------------------

## Parallelize subproc in bg
((count++)); do_job 10 &
((count++)); do_job 5  &
((count++)); do_job 1  &
((count++)); do_job 3  &
((count++)); do_job 7  &

wait;
echo "============================="
cat $jobout;
```

How to run each of these jobs (do_job) in parallel and still making it to wait and write the output in the order they were called.

The do_job has to be processed almost in parallel and queue in fifo and writing the output. Currently with the above code it is not happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "and still ... write the output in the order they were called". That's a tall/impossible order once you start running programs in the background. The only solution I see would be to add a key number at the front of each record and then sort the combined outputs after your backgrounding/parallel is done. You might find somthing in `man gnu-parallel` that can help you, if that is installed on your system (or if you can get it installed). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks. Currently I am using a key and removing it while finally writing. But I thought, if this can be accomplished with some locking and queuing mechanism.